# How to solve trigonometric inequalities like $\cos(x)<1$ without using inverse trig functions?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Basically the title, when I enter  $\cos(x)<1$ in symbolab I get these arccos relationships[image]

what I'm wondering is if there is a method, either graphically or numerically to solve these sort of inequalities without using properties of inverse trig functions ?

Comment: Well, it helps that $\cos (x)≤1$ for all real $x$.

Comment: Well, for the example you give, it's quite easy. We always have $\cos(x) \leq 1$, so you're asking for those numbers such that $\cos(x) \neq 1$. This is $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{ \frac{\pi}{2} + k \pi | k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since:

- $\cos(x)=1$ if and anly if $x=2k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$;
- $(\forall x\in\mathbb R):\cos(x)\in[-1,1]$,

you have $\cos(x)<1$ if and only if $x\in\mathbb R\setminus2\pi\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I Don't yet quite understand the $x\in\mathbb R\setminus2\pi\mathbb Z$ part

Comment: Note that $x\in\mathbb R\setminus2\pi\mathbb Z$ means that $x$ is *not* of the form $2k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: sure but how do I find and use these properties like $2k\pi$ to give a definite and accurate answer in other similar problems in trigonometry for that matter? What I mean is "what is the process" that gives these answers- is it  simply a property of cyclic functions or something like that?

Comment: The answer to that question depends upon which properties of the $\cos$ you can use. But the property$$\cos(x)=1\iff x\in2\pi\mathbb Z$$is a very basic one.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to use the definition of $\cos(x)$ that is $$ \cos(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$